# How to open pdf file in package path in android?

Tags: android

In my application i need to open pdf file.For that i have prepared code to open pdf file.Suppose my pdf file in sdcard, It is working fine.when my application change from sdcard to application path i.e `/data/data/app.package/` it is not working.I got alert dialog like
`Invalid file path` .Please guide me to over some this problem.

Comment: Post your complete code and file path. Also check your pdf file has a MODE_WORLD_READABLE permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/data/data/app.package/` is package private. To share this pdf you'd probably have to move it to external storage (you can use [getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29)). This directory has no security enforced.

Answer (score 0):

You must make /data/data/app.package/file.pdf redable for other applications.

1) using openFileOutput(fname, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE).close(); create share file in your app data directory.

2) write pdf file to created file using Streams (you may write to stream returnet by openFileOutput instead of close it)

3) open your pdf file