# Invalid filepath in database

Tags: android, sqlite, filepath

I have an app which keeps some data in local sqlite database file. On one of my devices, from time to time, trying to read this data leads to "Invalid filepath" dialog.

The code I used in SQLiteHelper to set database file path:

```
static String getEnvironmentPath() {
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
        return Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "custom.db";
    } else {
        return "custom.db";
    }
}
```

Actually, I´m not even sure that this invalid filepath popup is shown because of database, I get this error just on reading some data from database from time to time on one of my devices.

Initially thought that my case is something similar to [How to open pdf file in package path in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257944/how-to-open-pdf-file-in-package-path-in-android), but how comes that in the same database file 75% of data is read fine and 25% causes this error and only on one device?

What could be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What is exactly the purpose of the else case? Have you checked if the error is not happening when the else part is executed?

Comment: database is created just fine in else case, I checked it

Comment: Why don't you use SQLiteOpenHelper?

Comment: my class extends SQLiteOpenHandler

Comment: I´m not sure that sqlite causes "invalid filepath" dialog, since it happens on one device in about 25% cases

Comment: Also, this might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915690/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-getabsolutepath-not-working-and-givi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbelievable, but fact - deleting Adobe Reader from device solved the problem! I keep news in my app, and some of them contains flash video in html, so Adobe Player tried to open these and causes this "Invalid path" error.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have given permissions in Manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also, I am not sure if getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(...) is giving you the correct path. 
Just debug and check if you are getting the path

```
  /data/data/com.example.program/databases/xxx.db  or not !
```